# WPF animation question

Tags: wpf

I am new to WPF in general and want to add some animation to my interface.

I have a label and an image. The label will fly in from the right side of the window, the image from the left. They'll meet in the center. The image will rotate while its flying in, while the text will pretty much just move across the screen.

So my question is. For this kind of animation do you get a path object where you can draw a line at design time and have elements move across this line at a certain speed?

In classic windows forms I would have approached the issue using a timer and then adjust the left property of the label at each tick. Surely WPF is more sophisticated than this though.

So can anyone tell me a good approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: You need [ExpressionBlend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx) to create animation in WPF.

> WPF is more sophisticated

Of course no, read about [animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx) in WPF, Personally, I prefer [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/jennmar/animation-using-expression-blend-part-1-how-to-create-an-animation) learning for it.
you can find [here](http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx) some clips, I recommend [this](http://www.totaltraining.com/prod/microsoft/expblend2_ess.asp) series from Total training.

Comment: Blend is very useful, but it's trivial to create animations in WPF without it.